# Citrix Workspace crashing - Windows 10 GeForce GTX 970

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, citrix-receiver

I'm running Windows 10 with a GeForce GTX 970 Graphics card and connecting to Citrix using Citrix Workspace 20.2.0.25.

However twice today when selecting the Citrix session having been focused on my own PC, the entire machine freezes and I'm unable to recover it.

I was on Nvidia Graphics drivers 432.00 and upgraded to 442.74 just now.

I'm looking for some help in figuring out what is happening. I've tried setting logging on the Citrix session but that doesn't seem to work https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132883#1

Comment: Did you check Windows event logs? I would consider reinstalling Citrix Workspace without [app protection](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-windows/configure.html#app-protection).

Comment: Nothing in the event logs. I've uninstalled Citrix Workspace app but dont have any installation options to do without app protection. Seems likely to be an admin option to allow this or now.

Comment: The version made available by my company didnt have that option but directly from Citrix does. I have done that now. Why might this be a workaround/fix?

Comment: Just because that feature no longer could cause issues, if not installed. Easier to disable while connected: Flash acceleration - last tab in the the first screenshot [here](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/windows/current-release/improve.html).